# When using the urllib library, how to reconnect when the resulting page does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, urllib

When I use the urllib.request library to get the content of the site, I will receive the following error if the site has a connection error or does not exist

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10060]>
```

My code is like that

```
import urllib.request
while True:
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.198.129:8080/search.txt')
html = response.read().decode("gb2312")
print(html)
```

How do i let it be reconnected after losing the connection, rather than automatically exit.

THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, the standard way to handle exceptions is to [use `try` statement](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/errors.html):

```
while True:
    try:
        response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://192.168.198.129:8080/search.txt')
        html = response.read().decode("gb2312")
        print(html)
    except URLError as e:
        // code to execute in case of error
        print("That was an error :(")
        print(e)  # should print out more information about the error
```